# Why won't first div in this html display as a column next to the rest of the html that is float:right

Tags: html, css

Why won't first div in this html display as a column next to the rest of the html that is float:right?

```
<div style="padding-top:20px; float:left; width:50%; clear:both">Column 1</div>
<div class="" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right:20px; width: 50%; float:right; clear:both;">
  <label for="title">
    <h3 style="text-align:left">Column 2</h3>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right:20px; width: 50%; float:right; clear:both;">
  <input type="text" maxlength="255" value="">
</div>
<div class="" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right:20px; width: 50%; float:right; clear:both;">
  <label for="body">
    <h3 style="text-align:left">Column 2</h3>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right:20px; width:50%; float:right; clear:both;">
  <textarea maxlength="60000"></textarea>
</div>
```

Column 1 line forces column 2 down as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/coder/UQXvC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding of a box adds to its total width.

A box with the following CSS applied:

```
.box {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

will be 150px wide.

---

Since you're adding padding to your columns, they are effectively wider than 50%, and can't fit on the same row anymore.

Comment: even after removing all padding, the same result is achieved:  http://jsfiddle.net/coder/UQXvC/3/

Comment: Your columns have `clear:both` on them, which disallows other elements to appear on its row. See here with that removed: http://jsfiddle.net/UQXvC/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your css from your html.  then try something like

```
#col1{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
{

#col2{
 float:left;
 width:50%
}
```

play around with the width %'s and using left or right. using these divs:

```
<div id="col1"></div>
<div id="col2"></div>
```